# How to remove line by drawing another line over it

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, line

I need to delete the line which was previously drawn by putting another line over it. The new line should be the same color as the background.

I tried:
http://jsfiddle.net/wgenf10x/

```
<canvas id="canvas" style="background-color: black;">
```

Javascript:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");    
var screenW = canvas.width;
var screenH = canvas.height;
setColor("#ffffff");
draw();

      function setColor(colorHexStr){
        ctx.strokeStyle = colorHexStr;
      }


      function line(x1,y1,x2,y2){
        ctx.moveTo(x1,y1);
        ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
        ctx.stroke();
      }

      function draw(){
        setColor("white");
        line(0,0,screenW, screenH);
        setColor("black");
        line(0,0,screenW, screenH);
      }
```

But the white line is not completely erased. What is going wrong?

*P.S. Please do not suggest clearing the whole canvas. I don't need it.*

Comment: I see no lines in your demo.

Comment: You are seeing artifacts created by canvas's automatic anti-aliasing. Just increase the "erasing" lineWidth (`ctx.lineWidth+=1;`) to also over-write that anti-aliasing.

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is just an inherent "flaw" in the current canvas implementations. You need to clear -> redraw in order to be sure that your drawing is free from past artifacts.

Comment: @TennysonH. Well, anti-aliasing is not so much a flaw as a design standard that (unfortunately) can't be turned off when it needs to be off. ;-)

Comment: Implemented @markE's suggestion. Works great
http://jsfiddle.net/wgenf10x/2/

Comment: That trick only works when there's nothing else on the canvas though

Comment: @isick Thank you. You probably want to post this as an answer.

Comment: @DanielShatz it was markE's answer ;) Glad it worked out!

Comment: @SimonPlus. IMHO, the questioner has carefully tailored his question where the trick is applicable here. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing artifacts created by canvas's automatic anti-aliasing.

Just increase the "erasing" lineWidth (`ctx.lineWidth+=1;`) to also over-write that anti-aliasing.